# VBA - How to select multiple rows under specific header value

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a spreadsheet monthly that has a lot of data I don't need. The spreadsheet's rows are broken up sections and I am only interested in certain sections. Each section has a unique header to identify the rows below and a blank row in between each section. The number of rows in each section changes month to month but the headers are always constant.

Here is an excerpt from the spreadsheet:

[image]

I am trying to write a macro that deletes all rows under specific headers (including the headers) leaving only the data I am interested in. There are 72 sections every month and I want to remove all but 17 of them. For this example I want to delete the sections of "1100" but leave sections "1175" and "1202" as well as the column headers in tact. The addresses were removed but do NOT contain the section header.

My thought process was to select a header based on the cell value, which in this case is "1100", and delete the header row and every row below the header until a blank cell is reached.

I'm using the code below to try and delete the section for "1100" but I'm running into an issue. The issue is all of the rows aren't deleted and the selection seems to outpace the deleting of the rows leaving some behind.

```
Range(Cells.Find(What:="1100").Address.Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
   ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Thanks

Comment: When one deletes rows, one should loop from the bottom up.

Comment: Please share with us some of the xls rows, especially some headers with and without "1100".  Do the rows below the header also have the "1100" value, or just the headers?  Remove any proprietary data.

Comment: Would that resolve the issue I'm seeing with rows not getting deleted?

Comment: @Weiglert yes the reason it is skipping rows is that when one deletes a row the row below becomes the active row and then you move down.  Theoretically you can remove the `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` and it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like below. Put all the headers you want in an array. Find them and use Range delete and xldown to delete to the las blank row.

```
Sub DeleteSections()

Dim deleteHeaders As Variant
Dim sr As range
Dim fr As range

deleteHeaders = Array("Header 2", "Header 4")

Set sr = Application.range("A:A")

For Each Header In deleteHeaders

    Set fr = sr.Find(Header)

    If Not fr Is Nothing Then
    
        range(fr.Address, range(fr.Address).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete
  
    End If
        
        
Next Header

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all excuse my english

When VBA-Excel delete rows, all the rows on the worksheet are re-indexed, because the worksheets always keep the same number of rows.

This situation generates multiple problems in the results obtained.
Due to situation we can not use the "traditional" increment i = i + 1 presents in for/do loops.

To solve it, we should start with the final loop and then subtract 1 in the increment, like this i = i - 1

I recommend you use a sentence of this style:

```
'Defining variables
Dim inicial_row As Long, final_row As Long, i As Long

'Finding the value and Getting row from cell
    Cells.Find(What:="a").Activate
    inicial_row = ActiveCell.Row


'Getting the last row in the section (there should be no empty data inside the section)
    final_row = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row


'Using decrement in the loop

For i = final_row To inicial_row Step -1

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clean Data

- It is assumed that each header will occur only once.
- This solution requires all headers to be known, i.e. you will have to write 17 headers to `KeepList` and 55 headers to `DeleteList`.
- Basically, it will alternate between keeping all rows until an item from the `DeleteList` is found and deleting all rows until an item from the `KeepList` is found.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub cleanData()
    
    ' Constants
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const KeepList As String = "1175,1202"
    Const DeleteList As String = "1100"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define column range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RowOffset As Long
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(FirstCellAddress)
        RowOffset = .Row - 1
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - RowOffset).Find( _
            What:="*", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - RowOffset)
        RowsCount = rng.Rows.Count
    End With
    
    ' Write values from column range to array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If RowsCount > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write lists to arrays.
    Dim Keeps() As String: Keeps = Split(KeepList, ",")
    Dim Dels() As String: Dels = Split(DeleteList, ",")
    
    ' Write the indexes of matching values to a dictionary and an array list.
    ' The values in the dictionary will have value '1' for keeping and value '2'
    ' for deleting, while the array list will in the end be sorted.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Keeps)
        Key = Application.Match(Keeps(n), Data, 0)
        If IsNumeric(Key) Then
            dict(Key) = 1
            arl.Add Key
        End If
    Next n
    For n = 0 To UBound(Dels)
        Key = Application.Match(Dels(n), Data, 0)
        If IsNumeric(Key) Then
            dict(Key) = 2
            arl.Add Key
        End If
    Next n
    arl.Sort
    
    ' The second dictionary's keys will contain the first row to be deleted,
    ' while its values will contain the last row to be deleted (the rows
    ' referring to the rows of the range (not necessarily the worksheet)).
    Dim dict2 As Object: Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Key2 As Variant
    Dim isReady As Boolean
    For Each Key In arl
        If dict(Key) = 2 Then
            If Not isReady Then
                isReady = True
                dict2(Key) = RowsCount
                Key2 = Key
            End If
        Else
            If isReady Then
                isReady = False
                dict2(Key2) = Key - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next Key
    If dict2.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Delete rows.
    Dim dRng As Range
    For Each Key In dict2.Keys
        If dRng Is Nothing Then
            Set dRng = rng.Cells(Key).Resize(dict2(Key) - Key + 1)
        Else
            Set dRng = Union(dRng, rng.Cells(Key).Resize(dict2(Key) - Key + 1))
        End If
    Next Key
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    dRng.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use formulas where I can to avoid the overhead of VBA. It might be easier to automate adding these new columns than coding all in VBA?

This assumes your data is in a excel table with a column named "Data" where the header and/or data will appear.

Add a new column isHeader to the end of the data to identify if the row is a header, perhaps: `=OR(ROW()=1,OFFSET([@Data],-1,0)="")`

Add a column currentHeader to store the active header value:`=IF([@isHeader],[@Data],OFFSET([@currentHeader],-1,0))`

To filter to just the desired headers, I would add reference data in another worksheet that lists the desired headers and then a final new column - say `desiredHeader` that will return True when the value matches a reference value, else false (use vlookup, or countif etc).